# django filter __contains returns no value on a list while __in does

Tags: django, django-models

am essentially trying to perform a `select * from xyxtable where col like '%value%'` on a list of alphanumeric values from another dataframe column(prev_df['VendorPartNumber]. I thought the filter `__contains=` should do the trick. but this returns nothing

```
product_df=pd.DataFrame(Product.objects.filter(legacy_productid__contains=prev_df['VendorPartNumber']).values('id','legacy_productid'))
```

however using the __in to filter works (just that the result is not what I want since __in tests for equality)

```
product_df=pd.DataFrame(Product.objects.filter(legacy_productid__in=prev_df['VendorPartNumber']).values('id','legacy_productid'))
```

I tried a couple of things such as

```
     product_df= Product.objects.all()
        for search_term in perv_df['VendorPartNumber']:
            product_df = product_df.filter(legacy_productid__contains=search_term)
```

or

```
        product_df=pd.DataFrame(Product.objects.filter(reduce(operator.and_, (Q(legacy_productid__contains=x) for x in prev_df['VendorPartNumber']))).values('id','legacy_productid'))
```

what am I missing?

Comment: Are you able to provide some sample data that this fails with?

Comment: @solarissmoke am not sure I can... it is my 1st week at this company and I don't even know their no-nos yet around their data

Comment: @solarissmoke one thing that irked me on the data is the legacy_productid can be of the alphanumeric format "1234abc" or "0012345" where the amount of front padding zeroes can vary. if the value in VendorPartNumber is alphanumeric. it matches exactly what is in the legacy_productid (which explains why __in return them properly unlike when it is 0 padded numeric) so I figured __contains would match both alphanumeric and 0 padded if the numeric base is found

Comment: I wonder whether it is a combination of the type of data, and the database engine and how it handles `like` queries. Can't see anything obviously wrong with the Django filter.

Comment: @solarissmoke it is a PostgreSQL database

Answer (score 0):

I assume you want to retrieve the `id` of `legacy_product`.

In that case you have to do `legacy_product_id__contains='foobar'`.